# moment generating function basics

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

if X,Y discrete random variables such that Y=aX+b , how do I prove $M_y(t)=e^{tb}M_X(at)$.

My attempt:

$M_y(t)$=$\sum$$e^{tax}.e^{tb}p(y)$.    but then I notice this works iff p(x)=p(y) why is this the case? Thanks

Comment: It should be $p(x)$ there in your equation (double check that you understand how to [write the expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)). It is not true that $p(x) = p(y)$ but you don't need that here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
M_Y(t)=Ee^{tY}=Ee^{t(aX+b)}=Ee^{tb}e^{taX}=e^{tb}Ee^{(ta)X}=e^{tb}M_{X}(at)
$$

Comment: Just seen your answer. Sorry it took ages to type mine on my phone. +1

Comment: thanks both!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct using the properties of expectation but I admit it has been a while.  If I've made an error I will correct.

$\mathbb{M}_Y(t) =\mathbb{E} (e^{Yt} ) = \mathbb{E}(e^{(aX+b)t } ) =\mathbb{E}(e^{(aXt+bt) }) =\mathbb{E}(e^{aX }e^{bt})= e^{bt} \mathbb{E}(e^{(aXt) }) =e^{bt}\mathbb{M}_X(at) $